# Certificate revocation on IIS (CRL and OCSP)

Tags: iis, crl, ocsp

I need to figure out how certificate revocation works on IIS. Certificate we are working with contains both url to CRL and OCSP.

1. As I understand by default IIS uses CRL to verify if certificate is
   revoked, is that right? if it's true - can I just enable OCSP
   without stapling?
2. Can I configure IIS to use OCSP if we are unable
   to check revocation via CRL?
3. How can configure this only for specific site?